# How to fully uninstall python and reinstall it in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python3, software-uninstall, reinstall

Python is not configured or broken in my system Ubuntu 18.04. Can anyone suggest command to uninstall python and reinstall only python3.6

I ran below command : sudo apt auto remove

Andd when I try to run "apt update" or "apt upgrade" getting below error
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apport
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: If you **uninstall python** then you will not be able to re-install as `apt` will be broken!